# Unit -.mount is masked

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, systemctl

when I want to restart docker.service or start rabbitmq-server service (probably some other services too) It says:

`Failed to start "the service" : Unit -.mount is masked`

what should I do to fix it?

I read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/702738) but I don't think it was a solution, by the way here are the masked services in /lib/systemd/system:

```
(venv) root@debian:~# ls -l /lib/systemd/system | grep null | awk '{print $9,$10,$11}'
bootlogd.service -> /dev/null
bootlogs.service -> /dev/null
bootmisc.service -> /dev/null
checkfs.service -> /dev/null
checkroot-bootclean.service -> /dev/null
checkroot.service -> /dev/null
cryptdisks-early.service -> /dev/null
cryptdisks.service -> /dev/null
halt.service -> /dev/null
hostname.service -> /dev/null
hwclock.service -> /dev/null
killprocs.service -> /dev/null
motd.service -> /dev/null
mountall-bootclean.service -> /dev/null
mountall.service -> /dev/null
mountdevsubfs.service -> /dev/null
mountkernfs.service -> /dev/null
mountnfs-bootclean.service -> /dev/null
mountnfs.service -> /dev/null
rc.service -> /dev/null
rcS.service -> /dev/null
reboot.service -> /dev/null
rmnologin.service -> /dev/null
sendsigs.service -> /dev/null
single.service -> /dev/null
stop-bootlogd.service -> /dev/null
stop-bootlogd-single.service -> /dev/null
sudo.service -> /dev/null
umountfs.service -> /dev/null
umountnfs.service -> /dev/null
umountroot.service -> /dev/null
x11-common.service -> /dev/null
```

I've tried those solutions regarding unmasking but just doesn't work.

```
(venv) root@debian:~# sudo systemctl restart docker.service
Failed to restart docker.service: Unit -.mount is masked.
(venv) root@debian:~# sudo systemctl restart docker.service
Failed to restart docker.service: Unit -.mount is masked.
(venv) root@debian:~# sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service
Failed to start rabbitmq-server.service: Unit -.mount is masked.
(venv) root@debian:~# sudo systemctl unmask -.mount
systemctl: invalid option -- '.'
Hint: to specify units starting with a dash, use "--":
      systemctl [OPTIONS...] {COMMAND} -- -.mount ...
(venv) root@debian:~# sudo systemctl unmask -- -.mount
(venv) root@debian:~# sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service
Failed to start rabbitmq-server.service: Unit -.mount is masked.
```

If any other information is needed please let me know

Comment: Try to see the masked units with: `systemctl list-unit-files --state=masked`

Comment: Relevant debian bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=948710 Relevant question: https://superuser.com/questions/1497609/failed-to-start-openvpn-clientclientudp-service-unit-mount-is-masked

Comment: @TelinovDmitri In the systemctl list-unit-files the -.mount is masked-runtime not masked

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1497611/1725484) worked for me. the solution was just deleting some *.mount files!

Answer (score 2):

```bash
root@etcnode01:~# sudo service docker start
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service is masked.
```

**yeap,I also encountered the same problem, I think it is caused by repeated installation, try to eliminate it**

Comment: +1 My Rocky vagrant guest became unresponsive while installing docker, so I rebooted and attempted the install again, which looked like it worked, but after that I was getting the "masked" issue. On the basis of your idea, I uninstalled, re-installed, and now docker is working.